# Assert Method Error

Tags: c#, assert

I am using the line  `Assert.IsNotNull(object);` in my code. I keep getting the error:

> the name assert does not exist in the current content

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: (If my answer doesn't help you, please give more information.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` to your project references and add

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
```

Answer (score 4):

Is sounds like you don't have an appropriate `using` directive, such as

```
using NUnit.Framework;
```

in your code. The exact directive will depend on which unit testing framework you're using, of course. I'd expect you to get the same problem for other things though - particularly `[Test]` attributes etc.