# Error: The Name Assert Does Not Exist In The Current Context

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written some code to verify that a user can login to a hotel booking platform & I also added a verification step. I get an error
on the `Assert.IsTrue()` Method. Every other thing is fine in the code.

I did some research for a possible solution before stopping by.

Here is the solution I found on StackOverflow: [Assert Method Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695595/assert-method-error)

I have added Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework to my project references and also added

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting; & using NUnit.Framework; to my Using section of the code.

I get the following errors:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   CS0234 The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   PremierInn_Valid_User_Login c:\users\XXXX\onedrive\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2015\Projects\PremierInn_Valid_User_Login\PremierInn_Valid_User_Login\Program.cs
>   5 Active
>
> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   CS0246 The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   PremierInn_Valid_User_Login c:\users\XXXX\onedrive\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2015\Projects\PremierInn_Valid_User_Login\PremierInn_Valid_User_Login\Program.cs
>   6 Active

I get the same error after removing the bindings - Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting; & using NUnit.Framework.

And, finally here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PremierInn_Valid_User_Login {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

        //Instantiate Firefox Driver
        var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://secure.premierinn.com/en/mypremierinn/home.action");

        //Enter User Name - My Email Address
        var user = driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginForm.username"));
        user.SendKeys("abcdefg@gmail.com");

        //Enter Password - Account Pasword
        var pass = driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginForm.password"));
        pass.SendKeys("Testing123");

        //Click on Login button
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginForm.button")).Click();

        var loggedInHeader = driver.FindElement(By.Id("body-inner"));
        Assert.IsTrue(loggedInHeader.Displayed, "The user was able to successfully login.");

    }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions:

1. You are trying to write a unit test, but on a main program instead of in a unit test project?
   Create unit test project. [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx).
2. You are trying to use both NUnit and Microsoft Unit test framework? Choose one of them, not both.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to refer to the NUnit Assembly documentation to run a test with NUnit.

[NUnit QuickStart](https://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.6.4)

Comment: Thank you very much